# My first Brew gone wrong?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, stuck-fermentation

I attempted my first home brew from a kit last night, but underestimated how long the process would take so rushed it a little. After waking up this morning, I’ve realised I added the beer yeast into the wort while still hot! It’s undoubtedly killed the yeast as I can see no bubbles coming from my brew.

At this point can I just buy more yeast and add it now or is the whole brew now ruined?

Answer (score 5):

Yes yeast will get damaged and mostly die at 110°F+  anything over 120°F will kill in minutes, at 140°F it instantly kills the yeast.

**Just repitch some more yeast. You'll be fine.**

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't see any bubbles in the airlock, that doesn't mean that the beer doesn't ferment. But to be sure I would shake the wort vigorously to aerate it and then add a fresh pack of yeast. Maybe add some yeast nutrient.

If you've worked sanitarily, the wort should be fine. But the longer you wait, the greater the risk of infection.

Answer (score 0):

Lag time can vary depending on the yeast. Upwards of 24-48 hours are perhaps not that common. So if it were me I’d try to find a similar yeast if it possible and pitch it within 24 h. Dry yeast could be preferable to avoid a starter.

Comment: I'd say, do not wait 24 hr. If in doubt, just add yeast. More yeast will not hurt in 99% cases. Leaving warm wort without yeast for 24 hours leaves it prone to infection. I wouldn't risk ruining a batch of beer for a $5 sachet of dry yeast.